# What is wrong with this Quick Sort code

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I have spent hours looking at this quick sort code. Please help me find the error. It is reporting run-time error. In the code, I am taking the first element a[l] as the pivot.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class sorting
{
    public static int[] a = {7,2,6,4,3};
    public static void quickSort(int l, int h)
    {
        if(l<h)
        {
        int y=l+1;
        for(int g=l+1;g<h;g++)
        {
            if(a[g]<=a[l])
            {
                int t = a[g];
                a[g] = a[l];
                a[l] = t;
                y++;
            }
        }
        int k=a[l];
        a[l] = a[y-1];
        a[y-1] = k;
        quickSort(l,y);
        quickSort(y+1,h);
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        quickSort(0,5);
        for(int s=0;s<5;s++)
            System.out.print(a[s] + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: which runtime error is it returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why/how it was breaking:

In your code when `quickSort(l,h)` is called the values are `l=0` and `h=2`. These values make the if `if(l<h)` statement true and the function recurses again and again, 5,657 times actually. Then you get, ironically, a `StackOverflowError`.  The run time errors occur, I assume, because you are trying to recurse too deep.

Here is the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:480)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
    at sorting.quickSort(sorting.java:26)
    ... this error occurs 1024 times ...
```

There is a problem with you logic.

I determined that you were recursing too much by adding the following line to your code:

```
    a[l] = a[y-1];
    a[y-1] = k;
    System.out.println("l: "+l+" y: "+y); // I added this line.
    quickSort(l,y); // this is line 26 that the errors were mentioning
    quickSort(y+1,h);
```

I am not sure what all the of the other swapping outside the if statement is for.

### Fixed Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class sorting
{
    public static int[] a = {7,2,6,4,3};
    public static void quickSort(int l, int h) {
        if(l<h) {
            for(int g=l+1; g<h; g++) {
                if(a[g]<=a[l]) {
                    int t = a[g];
                    a[g] = a[l];
                    a[l] = t;
                }
            }
            quickSort(++l,h);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // updated this area incase more numbers are added.
        quickSort(0,a.length);
        for(int s=0;s<a.length;s++)
            System.out.print(a[s] + "");
    }
}
```

---

Comment: that means I don't need to swap the pivot back after partitioning ?

Comment: Yes, I think. I am not sure what all the other swapping was for. It helps to write debug lines `System.out.println` to dump out the variable values at different points to look at what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

really cant understand your code. And based on your code an alternative solution is :

```
public class sorting
{
   public static int[] a = {7,2,6,4,3};
   public static void quickSort(int l, int h) {
       if(l>=h||l<0){
           return;
       }
       int curStandard = l;
       for(int i = h; i > l;i--){//for
           if((a[i]>=a[curStandard]&&i>curStandard)||
                (a[i]<=a[curStandard]&&i<curStandard)){
               ;
           }else{//swap
               int temp = a[i];
               a[i] = a[curStandard];
               a[curStandard] = temp;
               curStandard = i;
           }
       }//for
       quickSort(l,curStandard-1);
       quickSort(curStandard+1,h);
   }

   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    quickSort(0,5);
    for(int s=0;s<5;s++)
        System.out.print(a[s] + "");
 }
}
```

the base idea is use the first element to divide origin array into two sub_array and make the same operation to sub_array.